# IS MFMailComposeViewController working on ipod 3.0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

IS MFMailComposeViewController working on ipod 3.0 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the iPod touch (to which I assume you refer) has at least one account configured in the Mail app, then yes, it should be able to present the `MFMailComposeViewController` UI. You can't rely on that being the case, though, even on an iPhone, and thus should always check whether `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` returns YES before displaying an instance of it.